# How to reduce the number of kernels/filters in a trained model in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

If I have a trained model, where I want to retrain the same model, with few filters/kernel removed from the existing model. e.g.

```
conv1 = tf.get_variable('conv1_1', shape=(11, 11, 3, 64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
```

and I want to resize this tensor such that it has the shape of (11, 11, 3, 20) but the same name and position, mean exactly the same variable. Advance thanks for the help.

I have tried `tf.reshape` but it gives me error of not matching the number of elements in a and b 
I have also tried `tf.assign(a,b, validate_shape=false)`

```
self.weights = {
    'conv1_': tf.get_variable('conv1_l1', shape=(11, 11, 3, 64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'conv2_': tf.get_variable('conv2_l1', shape=(7, 7, 64, 128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to transfer the weights of a pre-trained model to a new model. With the caveat that the new model has smaller number of filters ?

Comment: Not new model. i want to continue training the same model with new set of kernels/filters

Comment: Once you change the number of filters, it is no longer the same model. The architecture has changed. Do you agree ?

Comment: I think architecture is defined via number of variables and their interconnections. Number of variables and their interconnections remain same, here the case is to reshape a variable. i.e. 
'conv1_': tf.get_variable('conv1_l1', shape=(11, 11, 3, 64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
is a single variable with the given size, so while keeping this variable in place, to resize its shape. May be my concepts are not correct. sorry

Comment: Nope. The number of variables is not the same because the filter goes from dimension: (11, 11, 3, 64) -> (11, 11, 3, 20). Assuming the first 2 dimensions are your image size. This means your filter bank reduces from 64 filters -> 20 filters.
Hence the design of the network changes. I'll give it to you that the architecture (connections) remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is partially achievable.

Having an variable with the exact same name as one that's already defined is probably not possible. Because TensorFlow creates a data flow graph and each node needs to be uniquely identifiable (to avoid ambiguities). If you want the same name you can do that using [variable scoping](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope) having different scopes.

But for assigning a part of the variable to another you can use the following code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.variable_scope('old'):
  conv1 = tf.get_variable('conv1_1', shape=(11, 11, 3, 64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
with tf.variable_scope('new'):
  conv_res_1 = tf.get_variable('conv1_1', shape=(11, 11, 3, 20), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

assign_op = tf.assign(conv_res_1,conv1[:,:,:,:20])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  w_1, w_res_1 = sess.run([conv1, assign_op])
  assert np.all(w_1[:,:,:,:20] == w_res_1)
  print(w_1[0,0,0,0], w_res_1[0,0,0,0])
```

**Update**: If you're okay with losing the larger variable you can do the following. This will take conv_1 and replace the variable with a smaller variable.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
conv1 = tf.get_variable('conv1_1', shape=(11, 11, 3, 64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

assign_op = tf.assign(conv1, conv1[:,:,:,:20], validate_shape=False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  sess.run(assign_op)
```

Comment: Thank you @thushv89. Actually, I dont want to define another variable, but want to reduce the size of existing variable.

Comment: Further, I need to perform this action with in a session, and I saw in tf.reset_default_graph() documentation, that it wont work in the session.

Comment: The only option for that would be to copy the portion of weights to another variable. In TensorFlow you cannot modify the shape once a variable is defined.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by reset graph doesn't work in a session. Regarding the session and graph, when you define variables, unless a different graph specified they go to the default graph (You can try multiple graphs but that complicates the problem). Then session would execute parts of that graph depending on what you want in `session.run`.

Comment: I wonder, how come they decide this :) because at the same time tf.reshape works fine.

Comment: When you perform `tf.reshape` it returns a `Tensor`, not a `Variable` (which is not what you're looking for?)

Comment: And `reshape` doesn't grow/shrink the size of a variable. It just changes the shape, while keeping the number of elements constant.

Comment: Also about my first comment, you "can" change the shape of a `tf.Variable` so disregard that.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you are changing the number of parameters of your model. As you go from

```
conv1 = tf.get_variable('conv1_1', shape=(11, 11, 3, 64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

to

```
conv2 = tf.get_variable('conv2_l1', shape=(11, 11, 3, 20), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

Your learnable parameters goes from {Kernel x 64} to {Kernel x 20}
This will require you to re-train the network and learn its new weights.

However, this is a common problem that has evolved into a research area. Many methods have been proposed for this such as low-rank approximation of weights (Denton et al., 2014; Lebedev et al., 2014), weight quantization(Courbariaux et al., 2016; Rastegari et al., 2016), knowledge distillation (Hinton et al., 2014; Romeroet al., 2015) and network pruning (Han et al., 2015; Li et al., 2017), among which network pruning has gained notable attention due to their competitive performance and compatibility.

References to explore:

1. Emily L Denton, Wojciech Zaremba, Joan Bruna, Yann LeCun, and Rob Fergus.  Exploiting linearstructure within convolutional networks for efficient evaluation. InNIPS, 2014.
2. Vadim  Lebedev,   Yaroslav  Ganin,   Maksim  Rakhuba,   Ivan  Oseledets,   and  Victor  Lempitsky.Speeding-up convolutional neural networks using fine-tuned cp-decomposition.ICLR, 2014.
3. Matthieu Courbariaux, Itay Hubara, Daniel Soudry, Ran El-Yaniv, and Yoshua Bengio.  Binarizedneural networks:  Training deep neural networks with weights and activations constrained to+ 1or-1.arXiv preprint arXiv:1602.02830, 2016
4. Geoffrey Hinton, Oriol Vinyals, and Jeff Dean. Distilling the knowledge in a neural network.NIPSWorkshop, 2014.

Comment: Thank you @Nav . I am also working on network pruning. the theoretical solution, I have already built, but now facing tensorflow-specific issue. **This will require you to re-train the network and learn its new weights**  of course I have to train, but I need to train exactly the same model with the same graph but resized variable. technically it becomes a new architecture, but logically it remains same. because all variables and graph are in place, nothing changed. the variable internal structure has just changed.

Comment: I see. If its clear, you should close the Q. SO etiquette.

Comment: No no, I didn't mean that. Brother, I have a technical problem that how to resize a variable of a trained CNN model in tensorflow? I am sorry if I have mistakenly created any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I came to know that Tensorflow execute only static graph, so the number of filters can not be changed (the shape can be changed), in this regard, PyTorch is helpful, which can execute a dynamic graph.
I managed this issue by creating a new graph and copying the values of the desired filters into the new graph, discarding the selected filters.