# How to create multiple instances of a learning model in Tensorflow, CNN using python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have a class which can instantiate an object
  *et = EyeTracker()* 
where *EyeTracker()* is a class with ***init*** Constructor  as can be found [here](https://github.com/hugochan/Eye-Tracker/blob/master/itracker_adv.py). actually I want to create multiple models and assign some parts of one model to a newly created model and trash the old model. I am getting an error below. Any help will be highly appreciated. I am really stuck. I have also asked a question for the similar purpose [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313035/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-kernels-filters-in-a-trained-model-in-tensorflow/58315394). So both answers are welcomed.

```
def train(args):
    train_data, val_data = load_data(args.input)
    train_data = prepare_data(train_data)
    val_data = prepare_data(val_data)
    with tf.variable_scope("", reuse=True) as scope:
        et = EyeTracker()
        train_loss_history, train_err_history, val_loss_history, val_err_history = et.train(train_data, val_data, \
                                            lr=args.learning_rate, \
                                            batch_size=args.batch_size, \
                                            max_epoch=args.max_epoch, \
                                            min_delta=1e-4, \
                                            patience=args.patience, \
                                            print_per_epoch=args.print_per_epoch,
                                            out_model=args.save_model)
        save some parts of the (et)
        scope.reuse_variables()
        et = EyeTracker()
        Assign some parts of previous (et) to the new one and continue training
        train_loss_history, train_err_history, val_loss_history, val_err_history = et.train(train_data, val_data, \
                                            lr=args.learning_rate, \
                                            batch_size=args.batch_size, \
                                            max_epoch=args.max_epoch, \
                                            min_delta=1e-4, \
                                            patience=args.patience, \
                                            print_per_epoch=args.print_per_epoch,
                                            out_model=args.save_model)
```

the error is

> Variable conv1_eye_w does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
>   i am really sorry, if my question is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Partially resolved. I changed the default constructor init to a member function `initialize()` and passed the values as arguments, as shown below.

```py
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default(): 
            et = EyeTracker()
            et.initialize(96,256,384,64,96,256,384,64)            
            result_temp = et.train(n_epoch, train_data, val_data, lr=args.learning_rate, batch_size=args.batch_size, max_epoch=args.max_epoch, min_delta=1e-4, patience=args.patience, print_per_epoch=args.print_per_epoch, out_model=args.save_model)

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default(): 
            et = EyeTracker()
            et.initialize(80,256,384,64,96,256,384,64)           
            result_temp = et.train(n_epoch, train_data, val_data, lr=args.learning_rate, batch_size=args.batch_size, max_epoch=args.max_epoch, min_delta=1e-4, patience=args.patience, print_per_epoch=args.print_per_epoch, out_model=args.save_model)
```